# What is the state of the Malazan Empire at the end of the series?

Tags: malazan

So, I just finished re-reading all 10 books of "The Malazan Book of the Fallen".
In the Epilogue the following happens:

> Fiddler is doing what he said to his fellow Bonehunters in the last book: he is playing his fiddle in the Smiley's tavern in Malaz city and goes fishing.

Nothing is said about the empire itself and who is ruling it and what armies still are around to protect the land or even conquer more.

To not spoil too much, of whom we know that they survived, I have to ask the question(s) in spoiler tags, I hope this is ok:

> Is Ganoes still the last High Fist of the Host and his sister Tavore the Adjunct or are both or at least Tavore outlawed. Is Laseen still the empress or has Mallick Rel finished his betrayal and took over?

Answer (score 2):

So, after I finished reading Ian C. Esslemont's "Return of the Crimson Guard", I can partially answer my question on my own. Heavy spoilers ahead:

> The state of the empire and the fate of Laseen is revealed in this book: Many provinces rebel against the empire and one of the most dangerous parties are, as the title of the book implies, the Crimson Guard. In the end Laseen gets killed, Mallick Rel takes over and puts the First Sword Korbolo Dom into prison as he didn't stay at the front line during the battle.

Maybe the fates of other loved or hated characters is revealed in later books of Esslemont. I am now reading "Stonewielder" which picks up directly after "Return of the Crimson Guard".

> I still hope Mallick gets what he deserves for his betrayal of the Wickans...